# Manipulating Objects in Index

Tags: c#, arrays, object, listbox, indexing

So I was able to remove  by index but my question is there a way where I can remove objects by typing in the objects name?
Ex: Type in sara press button and it removes that object form my index.
My second question is there a way I can insert a new object into which ever index I want?

I am in windows form if you could help me or link me  tutorial I would be very greatful.

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        object[] names={"Sara", "Bill", "Martin", "Suasan", "Don"};
        listBox1.Items.AddRange(names);

    }

    private void btnRemoveByIndex_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //remove by index 

        int index = int.Parse(txtIndex.Text);
        if (index >= 0 && index < listBox1.Items.Count)
        {
                listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(index);
        }
        listBox1.ClearSelected();
    }

    private void btnRemoveByItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //remove objects
    }

    private void btnSpecIndex_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       //insert new object
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (listBox1.SelectedItem != null)
    listBox1.Items.Remove(listBox1.SelectedItem);
```

Comment: Doesnt seem to do anything

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer List rather than Array,

```
        List<string> Names;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Names = new List<string>();
            Names.Add("Sara");
            Names.Add("Bill");
            Names.Add("Martin");
            Names.Add("Susan");
            Names.Add("Don");
            listBox1.DataSource = Names;

        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (listBox1.SelectedItem == "Sara")
            {
                Names.Remove("Sara");
            }
            //To Insert a new Name at specific index say 1st
            Names.Insert(1, "Sample");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `listBox1.Items.Remove`

```
 object[] names = { "Sara", "Bill", "Martin", "Suasan", "Don" };
            ListBox listBox1 = new ListBox();
            listBox1.Items.AddRange(names);
            // give a same names value to remove item from listbox 
            listBox1.Items.Remove("Sara");
```

IF you want to insert item in specific index use

```
listBox1.Items.Insert(0, "tet");  //0 is index and "tet" is value
```

Comment: What about inserting new object into a specific index?